# EF4 Code first - delete all children when deleting parent from db?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a class that gets arranged into a hierarchy, such as this:

```
class TestContainer
{
... bla bla bla...
  public Virtual Item Items {get;set;}
}
Class Item
{
[Key]
public int ID {get;set;}
public string PropA {get;set;}
public string PropB {get;set;}



[InverseProperty("Parent")]
public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("Contents")]
public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have an update method that lets a user upload an updated set of children.

I didnt realize at first but deleting my container TestContainer doesnt delete the items.

Ok, No problem right?

I inserted the following functions (which is probably very ugly but I am still in the prototyping phase here)

```
   private void DeleteItems(TestContainer existingContainer)
        {

            //setup a flat list for deletion
            List<Item> trashCan = new List<Item>();
            //delete the old CI's from the database
            BuildDeletionList(existingContainer.Items, ref trashCan);

            foreach (Item item in trashCan)
            {
                context.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }


        private void BuildDeletionList(ICollection<Item> items, ref List<Item> trashCan)
        {
            if (items != null)
            {
                foreach (Item item in items)
                {

                    BuildDeletionList(item, ref trashCan);
                }
            }

        }

        private void BuildDeletionList(Item item, ref List<Item> trashCan)
        {

            if (Item.Children != null)
            {
                foreach (Item child in Item.Children)
                {
                    BuildDeletionList(item, ref trashCan);
                }
            }
        item.Children.clear();
            trashCan.Add(item);
        }
```

The problem here is that this either crashes my test server, or when I remove the recursive bit (and only remove parents -- testing out what is going wrong at this point), I get the following error

"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception."

How can I best cascade delete an Item and all of its Children, so that I do not have orphans in the database? (As I do now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of deleting an entity and its decedents using EF you can enable `Cascade delete` on the foreign key on your database. It is much more efficient than generating multiple delete statements.

Edit

You need to add `WillCascadeOnDelete()` when you configure the model

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(i => i.Children)
            .WithOptional(i => i.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Thanks :)     At any rate, Adding the appropriate [ForeignKey] tags and etc got my original model working, and what was apparnetly crashing the dev server was not .clear() ing the contents before removing each additional item the trashcan. I will use the cascade however, appreciate it!

Comment: Errr... How exactly do you enable cascade delete? Is it achievable with annotations or only fluent API?

Comment: Looks good, except I don't think it works on same-table sadly. On the plus side, this is exactly what you need to do when you have multiple-table parent/child.  I'm gonna mark this as answer with the hopes that this will fulfill most peoples' needs.

Comment: @Yablargo yes you are right. you need to drop the FK and manually create it with `cascade delete` in your `DatabaseInitializer`